# Force join anonymously to Teams meeting

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to make an app when user can schedule meeting with customer and sends the link to meeting by email. We encountered case when customer is logged on his Teams account in browser and he is joining with this account instead of as guest (anonymously). We want to force customer as unlogged. What we have tried:

1. Force open links in InCognito mode - we cannot due browser limitations.
2. Logout user from current logged account - it is not user friendly behavior and it is connected with some hacks
3. Open Teams in iFrame - we cannot do this due X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN in launcher page
4. Schedule meeting as online meeting does not work too

Have you any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: can you add details on where you retrieved the link and an example of the link